# Can Torbjorn pick up his own armor packs?

Tags: overwatch

In Overwatch, Torbjorn can lay armor packs on the ground for teammates to pick up. Is he also able to pick up his own armor packs?

Comment: I'm closing this question because the Armor Pack ability [has been removed from the game](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/news/patch-notes/pc/?page=2#patch-51575)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, Torbjörn can pick up his own armor packs.